# Рекурсивный http запрос, как дождаться последний дочерний элемент и только потом выдать результат?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Сначала получаем родительский обьект, затем надо пройтись по каждому и собрать его дочерние элементы. Сколько  в глубь у каждого из обьекта неизвестно. Идти до тех пор пока не пустой. После того только как получит по каждому родительскому обьекту результат, собрать в обьект один (Json) и выдать результат. Вопрос в том как сделать чтобы он ждал результат каждого род. обьекта.
Сейчас есть вот такой код, он записывает файл после получения каждой итерации ветки. А нужно как то дождаться последнию ветку и записать результат.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

try {
  getList();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
function recurs(res, a, parrentInfo, k) {
  http.get(
    "http:/..." + res,
    (resp) => {
      let data = "";
      resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      resp.on("end", () => {
        let count = 0;
        if (data !== "[]") {
          let dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
          a.push(dataJson);
          for (let i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
            k++;
            recurs(dataJson[i].id, a, parrentInfo, k);
            if (count == dataJson.length - 1) {
              fs.writeFileSync("5264.json", JSON.stringify(a));
            }
            count++;
          }
        } else {
        }
      });
      resp.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log({ error: err.message });
      });
    }
  );
}
async function getList() {
  http
    .get(
      "http://...",
      (resp) => {
        let data = "";
        resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on("end", async () => {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            let dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(dataJson.length);
            count = 0;
            let k = 0;
            let a = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
              let parrentInfo = dataJson[i];
              let result = await recurs(  dataJson[i], a,  parrentInfo, k );
            }
          }
        });
      }
    )
    .on("error", (err) => {
      console.log({ error: err.message });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, вам нужно полностью уйти от колбеков, чтобы построить всю логику внутри одной асинхронной рекурсивной функции. Для этого достаточно промисифицировать `http.get()` + использовать `response` как асинхронный итератор (`response`, как и любой поток чтения, реализует этот интерфейс).
Попробуйте решить при помощи этих кирпичиков:

1. Промисифицируем `http.get()`:

```js
function get(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    https.get(url, (res) => { resolve(res); });
  });
}
```

2. Получаем и обрабатываем ответ как асинхронный итератор:

```js
const response = await get(someUrl);
response.setEncoding('utf8');
let json = '';
for await (const chunk of response) {
  json += chunk;
}
const object = JSON.parse(json);
```